Is Diffusion Theoretically Proven to Be a Markovian Process, or Is It Just a Simplification?
I don't come from a physics background, but I'm curious—Is the diffusion process inherently and theoretically Markovian? Has this been mathematically proven or demonstrated through experiments, or is it more of a simplification to make the process easier to describe? If it's been proven, what are the key equations or experiments behind it?

You will always have a time scale. At the microscopic level it will, in the dilute regime, be the inverse of the collision frequency $w$. Hence, your processes will be correlated as: $we^{-wt}$. On any reasonable macroscopic time scale (say millisecond), the inverse of frequency of collision can be assumed to be 0. This effectively makes the autocorrelation of most processes go to a dirac delta effectively rendering your system markovian on the macroscopic scale

Yes, diffusion is a Markovian process. To give an exact answer, one would have to define exactly what we call diffusion (which is not specified in Q.)
E.g., if we consider as diffusion a process described by a Fokker-Planck equation (of which the diffusion equation is a particular case), then we can solve this equation to the probability $P(x,t|x_0,t_0)$ that a particle starting at point $x_0$ at time $t_0$ finds itself at point $x$ at time $t$. This probability then satisfies the compositional property, otherwise called Smoluchowski equation:
$$
P(x,t|x_0,t_0)=\int dx' P(x,t|x',t')P(x',t'|x_0,t_0).
$$
This equation demonstrates, that the probability that a particle arrives to a certain point depends only on this previous point and not on the prehistory, which is the Markovian property. More generally (without Markovian assumption) we would expect:
$$
P(x,t|x_0,t_0)=\int dx' P(x,t|x',t', x_0,t_0)P(x',t'|x_0,t_0).
$$
